# I want to show CMB2 meta fields on specific product category on backend

Tags: wordpress, post-meta, cmb2

I need to show cmb2 meta fields based on specific product category in backend. Like there is a product is already assigned to t-shirt category and another product is assigned to shirt category. Both of them has separate cmb2 post meta. What I want is show meta for t-shirt when editing a t-shirt category product and other meta for shirt when editing a shirt category product. I tried some of the examples they provided and checked ticket response in their git repository but none of the solution works.

Thanks in advance.